# QBO3 database deployment does not create Entity view

Tags: sqlproj, qbo3

When deploying a database theme to create a new QBO3 database, the Entity view was not created.

My theme includes references to the following .sqlproj projects:

- Standard
- Mortgage
- Credit
- Debt

And I see that the Standard.sqlproj > Scripts > Script.PostDeployment.sql includes creation of an Entity view if it does not already exist.

Do I need to deploy each project separately?

Answer (score 1):

To include pre-and-post deployment scripts from "core" projects, modify your theme's pre-and-post deployment script to **include the relevent scripts** from the other projects.

For example:

```
:r ..\..\Standard\Scripts\Script.PostDeployment.sql
:r ..\..\Mortgage\Scripts\Mortgage.PostDeployment.sql
```

Note that the `:r` syntax is a [SQLCMD convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj889461(v=vs.103).aspx) to include external files. The included files will be run in the order in which they are included.